# Criteria API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following (simplified) entity structure:

```java
public class Animal {
  private long id;
  private int regionId;
  private int categoryId;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "animal")
  private List<Attributes> attributes;
}

public class Attributes {
  private long id;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Animal animal;
  private String name;
  private String value;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Detail detail;
}

public class Detail {
  private long id;
  private String size;
  private String type;
}
```

This is part of a Spring Boot application.

What I would like to achieve is to query **Animal** by both their own attributes and by attributes in **Details**.

My query needs to look like this:

```
GET: /animal/{regionId}/{categoryId}?size=medium,large&type=carnivorous,herbivore
```

This would mean that I need to request all animals that have a certain regionId and categoryId and that also have **Details** with size and type within the value list provided. Also - and I think this is the tricky part - the *size* and *type* parameters are optional, so the query needs to take that into account.

Currently I have a PlanReposiory that extends CrudRepository and provides basic query methods for the **Plan** entity.

I was trying to wrap my head around the Criteria API to figure out a way to use it to achieve this goal, but I don't understand how I can put all that in my repository. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at Spring Data JPA Specifications:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

You have to extend your Repository from JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
public interface CustomerRepository 
       extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
 …
}
```

And then you the a findAll method that takes Specification paramter:

```
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);
```

Then you can create your specification based on the parameters passed in the URL:

```
public static Specification<Animal> bySizeAndType(String size, String type) {

    return new Specification<Animal>() {

      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Animal> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder builder) {

         // JOIN Attributes
         // JOIN Detail

         if (size != null) {
           // add condition
         }
         if (type != null) {
           // add condition
         }

         return builder.where(...);
      }
    };
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I 'm starting to see the picture. How would the join and the condition look like in this case?

Comment: You should buy a book or read the Java EE tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria003.htm